# My Pull Request changes have been approved, but the forked branch is now several commits behind

Tags: github, pull-request

New to GitHub.

I started a Pull Request on a favorite repository of mine, and I have all all three green checks now signifying that my changes have been approved, that all checks have passed, and that there are no conflicts with the base branch.

I noticed that my forked branch is now 60 commits behind the base branch though. Will this be a problem when the repository owner tries to merge the branch? If so, what should I do?

Comment: No, it won't cause a problem. If there would be some conflicts, GitHub would tell it near the Merge PR button.

Answer (score 0):

git fetch it, git rebase it on origin/master.  re-push --force your branch (which just means "take this merge request branch literally and don't try to merge it with what is currently pushed to this branch") after you resolved all conflicts.

after 60 commits, it could be quite a lot of conflicts.  but when you use git normally, you do conflict resolution during rebase (of publicly published commits).

from your comment, i would assume that you are at a stage where you avoid merge; and should only do fast-forward merges of branches forked off of what you are merging it into.  (ie: fixDockerComposeBug ... git checkout -b fixDockerComposeBug_experiment .... git checkout fixDockerComposeBug ... git merge fixDockerComposeBug_experiment .... git push origin fixDockerComposeBug).

i'm not sure how familiar you are with git, but be careful in taking the advice to use "--force".  only do that against your unmerged branches; never against something shared.